# Nushell: Convert list of records to table

Tags: text-processing, json, nushell

<sub>*Disambiguation note:  I originally titled this "Nushell: Convert list to table" (and some search engines have this as the first result for those words), however [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73588877/11810933) may be a better "list to table" example.*</sub>

---

Is there an idiomatic way to convert a list of similar records into a table in Nushell?

I'm working with the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com) and getting results back something like:

```
let questions = ('[
  {
    "tags":
    [
      "nushell"
    ],
    "title": "Nushell: Convert list to table"
  },
  {
    "tags":
    [
      "ssh",
      "tar"
    ],
    "title": "tar through ssh session",
    "closed_reason": "Duplicate"
  }
]' | from json)
```

Notice that `closed_reason` is only returned for questions that were closed, of course.  That makes sense -- No need for the API to waste bandwidth returning empty fields for most questions.

But as a result, `$questions` becomes a `list<any>` in Nushell.  That means that an operation like:

```
> $questions | group-by closed_reason
```

... results in a (logically) `cannot find column` error.

All results need to have the same structure for this to work.  For instance, if all results had `closed_reason`'s, like so:

```
let questions = ('[
  {
    "tags":
    [
      "nushell"
    ],
    "title": "Nushell: Convert list to table",
    "closed_reason": ""
  },
  {
    "tags":
    [
      "ssh",
      "tar"
    ],
    "title": "tar through ssh session",
    "closed_reason": "Duplicate"
  }
]' | from json)
```

Then `$questions | describe` becomes:

```
table<tags: list<string>, title: string, closed_reason: string>
```

And `$questions | group-by closed_reason` will work.

Is there any way to convert/"normalize" the list to a table?

I've tried (with the original, `list<any>` result):

```
> $questions | table | group-by closed_reason
# obviously doesn't work, since the table command is just for rendering
# but worth a shot

> $questions | to csv | from csv | group-by closed_reason
# works, but loses the tag lists

> $questions | transpose | transpose | headers | reject column0 | to json
# Almost works, but still results in a list<any>
# since the first question's closed_reason becomes null
> $questions | transpose | transpose | headers | reject column0 | group-by closed_reason
# results in "can't convert nothing to string"
```

Comment: You can tell that `nushell` should be avoided because they included a phonetic `new` in it's name. In 20 years time it won't be new (see the ancient "new awk", nawk, for example). If the providers didn't know to avoid that beginner mistake in the name of the tool (it's very well known that no software should include the word "new"), that should be a warning about how well the tool itself has been designed/implemented.

Comment: I see a close-vote on this saying it should be on Stack Overflow.  While I have posted a separate Nushell question there a few days ago that was *scripting* related, this one is more *usage* than scripting, so I felt Unix & Linux is a better fit.  It would like be closed on Stack Overflow as off-topic (general computing).  It's the same reason we would see `jq` questions being more on-topic here on U&L than on SO.

Comment: @EdMorton Or perhaps then it will simply be ironic, in the same way that [Fish](https://fishshell.com) says of itself, *"Finally, a command line shell for the 90s"* ;-).  That's assuming it's around at all (I think it will be), or they haven't renamed it (still plenty of time for that if they want, as a 0.61 release currently).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use the question mark operator as explained in the official [documentation](https://www.nushell.sh/book/variables_and_subexpressions.html#variable-paths):

```
❯ $questions | group-by closed_reason?
╭───────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│           │ ╭───┬─────────────┬─────────────────────────┬───────────────╮ │
│ Duplicate │ │ # │    tags     │          title          │ closed_reason │ │
│           │ ├───┼─────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────────────┤ │
│           │ │ 0 │ ╭───┬─────╮ │ tar through ssh session │ Duplicate     │ │
│           │ │   │ │ 0 │ ssh │ │                         │               │ │
│           │ │   │ │ 1 │ tar │ │                         │               │ │
│           │ │   │ ╰───┴─────╯ │                         │               │ │
│           │ ╰───┴─────────────┴─────────────────────────┴───────────────╯ │
╰───────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

Comment: Excellent - Thanks!  I actually *did* miss that the "optional"/`?` syntax had been added for that.  That's a nice alternative to `default` - A bit different, since `default` keeps the null results (after renaming) and `?` drops them, but that would be desirable in some cases, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unfortunately unfamiliar with the `nu` shell. Still, you could definitely pass the data as JSON through to `jq`, add the missing keys with empty string values, and then convert it back to the shell's internal representation.

Here I'm updating the `questions` variable, but you could tag the `jq` command onto the original `let` command instead of converting the data back and forth needlessly.

```
let questions = ($questions | to json | jq '.[].closed_reason += ""' | from json)
```

Then you can group it by the `closed_reason`:

```bsh
〉$questions | group-by closed_reason
╭───────────┬───────────────╮
│           │ [table 1 row] │
│ Duplicate │ [table 1 row] │
╰───────────┴───────────────╯
```

Comment: Thanks - Good point.  While I'm hoping to avoid/reduce my usage of `jq` with Nushell, there are almost certainly still going to be cases where it will be easier than the equivalent in Nushell.

Comment: Btw, looks like you actually loaded it up since you posted the actual prettified-table output that it generates?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Yes, I installed the shell on macOS, loaded the data from the question, and played around with it, dipping into the web-based manual (at https://www.nushell.sh/book/) every once in a while.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the answer.  I happened to be looking for something entirely different with `help --find def`, when I spotted the appropriately named (but not referenced in the Nushell Book) `default` command, which is essentially a Nushell built-in for doing the same thing that [@Kusalananda's recommended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/701016/432493) with `jq`.

So the example in the question can be fixed via:

```
> $questions | default "" closed_reason | group-by closed_reason
╭───────────┬───────────────╮
│           │ [table 1 row] │
│ Duplicate │ [table 1 row] │
╰───────────┴───────────────╯
```

And the result is a real Nushell table object:

```
> $questions | default "" closed_reason | describe
table<tags: list<string>, title: string, closed_reason: string>
```

With that in place, I can start doing some slicing and dicing on the Stack API:

```
> $questions |
      default "" closed_reason | 
      where closed_reason == "Duplicate" |
      update tags { $in.tags | str collect ','}
      
╭───┬─────────┬─────────────────────────┬───────────────╮
│ # │  tags   │          title          │ closed_reason │
├───┼─────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ 0 │ ssh,tar │ tar through ssh session │ Duplicate     │
╰───┴─────────┴─────────────────────────┴───────────────╯
```